# mono mac osx csharp win forms gdi font exception but not using any MS font

Tags: c#, macos, mono, winforms-interop

We are trying to run a C# Win Form application on Mac OSX that we have rewritten. With the previous version, everything win form related was working, but now we get that on Mac :

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.ArgumentException: The requested FontFamily could not be found [GDI+ status: FontFamilyNotFound]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor (GenericFontFamilies genericFamily) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.FontFamily:.ctor (System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies)
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_GenericSansSerif () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont (System.String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte charSet, Boolean isVertical) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, Single emSize, System.String systemName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Font:.ctor (string,single,string)
  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeVisualStyles..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NewWorldStudio.StartupForm..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NewWorldStudio.StartupForm:.ctor ()
  at NewWorldStudio.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.ArgumentException: The requested FontFamily could not be found [GDI+ status: FontFamilyNotFound]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor (GenericFontFamilies genericFamily) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.FontFamily:.ctor (System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies)
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_GenericSansSerif () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont (System.String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte charSet, Boolean isVertical) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, Single emSize, System.String systemName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Font:.ctor (string,single,string)
  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Theme..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeVisualStyles..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NewWorldStudio.StartupForm..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NewWorldStudio.StartupForm:.ctor ()
  at NewWorldStudio.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It's been hard to find a solution on Google. It seems related to GDI+ and Sans Serif font as per the get_GenericSansSerif method in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's caused by a bad setup of Mono. Try to install again and check if you have X11 installed on OS X.